# How to make a "macro" to automate some bash commands in OS X Terminal?

Tags: bash, unix, macros, terminal

I'm pretty decent with bash and UNIX commands, and the Terminal app, but I'm wondering, is there a way to make a "macro" (maybe that's the wrong word!) to automate some tasks?

For example, to get into my current project directory, I type:

```
$ cd ~/Documents/College/F13/CS362/lab3/os-lab-3
```

And then I immediately do

```
$ hg pull
```

(password)

And then

```
$ hg update
```

So is there a way to even automate that first step of the cd call? I've never tried anything like that before, not sure if what I'm going for is even possible.

Bonus: is there a way to have the macro enter my password when prompted as well? Security/privacy is not really an issue here, there's no thermonuclear codes hiding around in the repo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name generally used in this context (a macro in bash) is [shell script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script). To automate the commands from your post you would need to create a file with a name like 'myscript.sh' with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Documents/College/F13/CS362/lab3/os-lab-3
hg pull
hg update
```

The first line of the script is a [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). This is a special comment line which indicates that file should be executed using the indicated program. Bash in this case.

To run the script first ensure that it is executable by running the following command:

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

From there in terminal window just run the script by specifying the path to it:

```
./myscript.sh
```

Don't put passwords into shell scripts though! It is a bad habit. For authentication with Mercurial an ssh key pair is the best way to go. The ssh key can be loaded into OSX's keychain, so you won't have to type anything when you run the script. You'll also need to add the public portion of your ssh key pair to the list of authorized hosts on the remote Mercurial repository.

Comment: Wow thank you, this is the best answer I've ever gotten on here. Shell Scripts huh? I guess I'll need to learn some of that. This is really cool! Will save me a lot of time!! Thanks!

Comment: One thing: the bit in your answer about ssh key loading into OSX keychain...any suggestions on how to do that? key/value pair stuff has always eluded me.

Comment: It would be a good idea to have some sort of error handling in this script, even if it's only adding ` -e` to the hashbang (which tells bash to exit the script if any command report an error). Otherwise, if the `cd` command fails for some reason, you'll be running `pull` and `update` on whatever directory you happen to be in... not at all what's intended.